# How can I make a responsive parallelogram in SVG keep it's angles?

Tags: html, xml, svg, responsive-design

Let's start with the end-result I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Where the length and height of the parallelogram can change independently of each other, but where the angle of the sides do not change.

With that out of the way, let's talk about why and what I've already done.

I'm fairly inexperienced with SVG, but I already know that CSS isn't enough to do what I want to do, which is to make responsive buttons that look like the above image - except that sometimes the left or right side is straight.

Initially, for those, I designed a massively wide SVG that could be used as a background and then scaled up and aligned to the left or right (as a background) so that the excess gets cut off but so that the aspect ratio does not change.  For some reason that I haven't spent any time debugging, that does not work as designed.

Then, I learned a little bit more about SVG and learned about preserveAspectRatio.  I used this nifty feature to make SVGs that themselves were responsive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="main-box" viewBox="0 0 200 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect x="22" height="50" width="178" style="fill:green;">
    </rect>
    <svg id="left-corner" viewBox="0 0 27 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <polygon points="22,0 27,0 27,50 0,50" style="fill:green;"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="main-box" viewBox="0 0 200 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin slice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect height="50" width="178" style="fill:green;">
    </rect>
    <svg id="right-corner" viewBox="0 0 27 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet">
        <polygon points="0,0 27,0 5,50 0,50" style="fill:green;"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

These two very easily maintain the aspect ratio of the triangle making up the side (meet) while forcing the rectangle to expand to fill the remaining space.  Perfect!  It does this using xMaxYMin when the triangle is on the right and xMinYMin when the triangle is on the left.

However, and fairly obviously, this approach doesn't work when you want one on the left **AND** one on the right!

My first attempt was a fairly silly trial of xMidYMin, which put the viewport on the center of the rectangle, but as the height expanded the edges went further outward and the triangles never showed themselves - instead rendering one gigantic rectangle!

My next attempt was very close, by removing the rectangle I achieve *nearly* my desired effect!

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="main-box" viewBox="0 0 50 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <svg id="left-corner" viewBox="0 0 27 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <polygon points="22,0 27,0 27,50 0,50" style="fill:green;"/>
    </svg>
    <svg id="right-corner" viewBox="0 0 27 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet">
        <polygon points="0,0 27,0 5,50 0,50" style="fill:green;"/>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

The problem here though, is that while it does expand up and down, the longer it gets the more it indents from the end!

I've also tried embedding both the start and end cuts as separate SVG into one SVG with a width of 50% (one on each side) but the embedded SVGs are stretched instead of resized when preserveAspectRatio is off for the main image, and it doesn't expand to fill space the way I need it when it's on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="main-box" viewBox="0 0 200 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <svg id="start-cut" viewBox="0 0 200 50" width="50%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect x="22" height="50" width="178" style="fill:green;">
        </rect>
        <svg id="left-corner" viewBox="0 0 27 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
            <polygon points="22,0 27,0 27,50 0,50" style="fill:green;"/>
        </svg>
    </svg>
    <svg id="end-cut" viewBox="0 0 200 50" width="50%" x="50%" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin slice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect height="50" width="178" style="fill:green;">
        </rect>
        <svg id="right-corner" viewBox="0 0 27 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin meet">
            <polygon points="0,0 27,0 5,50 0,50" style="fill:green;"/>
        </svg>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

What can I do to keep both the left and right corners in their proper place, with their proper angle (so they must keep their aspect ratio) while the middle expands (does not need to keep it's aspect ratio)?

Comment: @Ivar No.  For my personal use case I ended up using CSS to skew the div and then an inner span that I unskewed.  It appears there is no SVG specific approach.. though now that I've said that, and CSS is valid in SVG.. perhaps you can skew in SVG?

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Also, after a bit more reading, I found the svg [transform attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) .

That can be used to do a skew transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code for a responsive SVG parallelogram:

```
<svg id="main-box" viewBox="0 0 2000 500" preserveAspectRatio="none" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <style>
  rect {
    fill:black;
  }
  </style>
  <rect x="190" y="0" width="90%" height="100%"  transform="skewX(-20)" />
</svg>
```

Note the use of the skewX transform and the rect and width values to give the SVG its shape. It works fine. However, the only issue I had was when trying to use this as a background image on the body tag. There was an issue with incorrect sizing in Firefox. Researching the issue, it seems to be caused by different interpretations of the spec, rather than an unintentional bug.

You can see the use of this parallelogram on a side project I created: https://thisisa.lockdownchemz.link/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Is it something like this :

```
<svg id="main-box" viewBox="0 0 100 40" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <polygon points="0,0 73,0 100,40 27,40" />
</svg>
```